# Relating 3 or more tables using Statistical Query

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, yii

I am trying to relate 3 tables in Yii using statistical query. I need to display the minimum rate for each requests that is posted by a logged in user with the condition where "communications"=hai and "Country" = China where communications and country are attributes of 3 different tables. How can I implement this? Is there any method to add AND/Or in condition of statistical query. My code is as shown..

```
   return array(                     
                         'serviceproposals' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Serviceproposal', 'ServiceRequestID'),
                         'user' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Buyer', 'user_id'),
                         'postCount'=>array(self::STAT, 'serviceproposal', 'ServiceRequestID'),
                         'maxvalue'=>array(self::STAT, 'serviceproposal', 'ServiceRequestID','select'=>'MAX(proposal_amount)'),
                         'minvalue'=>array(self::STAT, 'serviceproposal', 'ServiceRequestID','select'=>'MIN(proposal_amount)', 'condition' => 'Communications ="hai"'),
                    );
```

Database:

```
User[user_id,name,password,Country],
Provider[user_id,providercompany,providerdetails],
Buyer[user_id,contactinfo],
ServiceRequest[ServiceRequestID,Buyer.user_id,details,date],
ServiceProposal[ServiceProposalId,ServiceRequestID,Provider.user_id,services,propsal_rate,Communications]
```

Answer (score 0):

In Yii if we use STAT Queries normally performance of query gets affected because STAT is slow. Instead of adding relation ship you can use COUNT in CDBCriteria select option and to get use of it we need to declare that property into model 
Like in Serviceproposal model you need to add property public $postCount; So you can use the value of count from out put.

Comment: @bool.dev How can I implement this in Statistical Query

Comment: Is there any way to add changes to condition in ` 'minvalue'=>array(self::STAT, 'serviceproposal', 'ServiceRequestID','select'=>'MIN(proposal_amount)', 'condition' => 'Communications ="hai"'),` for adding the third table

Comment: Are you using CDbCriteria OR you only use relations?

Comment: If you use CDbCriteria all your problems will solve. just need work little at relations. Here you need to add 
In your select parameter  
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->select = "SELECT MIN(proposal_amount) AS min_proposal_amount";
$criteria->condition = "";
But the alias should be declared in model 
Like 
Class Serviceproposal extends ActiveRecordModel
{
  public $min_proposal_amount;
}